# error: cannot find symbol addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.rms)

Tags: java, android, xml, rom

As the title say i'm trying to compile Settings from sources for LP but i've got this error...
I tried to change the xml name of the file but it still persists.

Here is the original code:

```java
package com.android.settings.reborn;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;

import com.android.settings.R;
import com.android.settings.SettingsPreferenceFragment;

import java.util.List;

public class RMainSettings extends SettingsPreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.rms);
    }
}
```

The rms.xml file is located in res/xml so don't ask me that :p

Comment: How does the rms file look?

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/z1MYamcW